# Regex catch 0 or 0.0 or 0.00

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a tough question: I use `(^[1-9]\d*|\d+\.\d*[1-9])$`, I want to find zero-sum like 0 or 0.0 or 0.00 or 0000, but that regex says to me 60. or 60.00 or 62.0 etc not valid (equal zero). What I do wrong?

[These examples for valid or not valid sum](https://regex101.com/r/dqqkqy/5)

Thanks!

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear. What would you like to match and what is/isn't matching?

Comment: Add input and Output example

Comment: I would like to match 60. or 60.0 or 60.00 or 02.0 or 02.00 etc, all that I want to match the VALID section, all that I don't want a match in the NOT VALID section. Check my link pls. Thx

Comment: You should look for a number different than 0. Why do you want to do it with regular expression? Regex is for format, not for the value.

Comment: Because I use custom validatorjs https://github.com/skaterdav85/validatorjs#register-custom-validation-rules

Comment: @Ilya make it two rules - one for being a floating point number and one for being greater than 0.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try the following regex it does respect your criteria (valid, not valid)

```
^(?:0?[1-9]\d*(?:\.\d*[0-9]*)?)|(:?^0.[1-9]+0)$
```

https://regex101.com/r/dqqkqy/6

After change in requirements to accept `0.1, 0.2, 0.3`:

```
^(?:0?[1-9]\d*(?:\.\d*[0-9]*)?)|(:?^0.[1-9]+0?)$
```

https://regex101.com/r/dqqkqy/8

Comment: Wow, thx. But I forgot 0.1 or 0.2 etc valid value. https://regex101.com/r/dqqkqy/7 Could u help?

Comment: @Ilya: I have edited the answer, could you have a look thanks?

Comment: Thanks a lot! You very much helped me!

Comment: @Ilya: No prob, if you liked my answer, you can also upvote it ;-) Thanks!!! And good luck with the rest of your implementation

Comment: But how can I fix the 0.03 value not valid? How can I fix it? https://regex101.com/r/dqqkqy/10